Can we include post index variables in a logistics regression
Can we include post index event in logistic regression if teh event is before the end point?
I have to do a regression to understand which patients stay on medication. I have taken the index date as the date they start with Medicine x. All characteristics of patients before starting the medication x ( baseline char) are used to predict weather they stay on tretment till 1 year. I am interested in adding a variable to see the effect of medicine at 6 months to this regression. Can I do that or is it not statistically sound because essentially this variable is post index ?
Stay on treatment for 1 year ( 1 or0) ~ patient characteristics before starting treatment + effect of of treatment at 6 months

Well, I don't think it makes much sense to include post-index variables, at least for the obvious application of the model, which is to help make decisions about what to do (give this treatment or do something else) at the index time. Although this question is interesting, it's off topic here; try [stats.SE] instead.
